# How to add Multiple Group By with different conditions output in single query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

Hello I am new to mongodb from sql,
I want a particular data in mongodb which can be easily available in sql using subquery
Please help how to get the required output in mongodb .

**Need to get average of students in different subjects in single object with student name**

Stored Object :

```
[
{StudentsName:"AKshay",_id:"feferf","subject_name":"SubjectA","marks":"28"},
 { StudentsName:"AKshay",_id:"feferf","subject_name":"SubjectB","marks":"50"} , 
{StudentsName:"AKshay",_id:"feferf","subject_name":"SubjectA","marks":"28"},
  {StudentsName:"AKshay",_id:"feferf","subject_name":"SubjectB","marks":"50"},
]
```

Required output:

```
{StudentsName:"AKshay",_id:"feferf","SubjectA":"28","SubjectB":"50"}
```

Have used group by using match but it gives different array object in different objects with same _id .
Even tried facet...

Comment: each document should have different `_id` if you can give valid json data, its almost ok, but i didn't see that you put the same `_id` and i thought that something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I see a design smell here, why do you have a different document for each note? I guess that you're thinking in transactional DBs but using a Document DB, where you could have different levels and add all the notes to a single document.

Said that, you can make this query with aggregation pipelines, here yo have how:

```
[{$group: { // First you need to group your data, I think that you could save the data already in that format and use only one step in the aggregation pipeline.
 _id: '$StuddentName',
 notesA: {
  $push: {
   $toInt: '$SubjectA' //Why your notes are strings? you could avoid the $toInt using integers directly
  }
 },
 notesB: {
  $push: {
   $toInt: '$SubjectB'
  }
 }
}}, {$project: { // Here is where you get the AVG
 avgA: {
  $avg: '$notesA'
 },
 avgB: {
  $avg: '$notesB'
 }
}}]
```

Or, even better, you can use the solution suggested by @takis which use only a step: https://cmql.org/play/?q=70314926

You can find the complete aggregation operators in the [official mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and if you are using mongo compass or Atlas the aggregations tabs is pretty useful to try your pipelines.

Comment: you can do both in 1 step i think like [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70314926) because avg works both on arrays and as  accumulator

Comment: You're right! I'm going to add your solution in my answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply went through the solution and it works if I have key as "subject A" have updated the document please check if you both can help

Comment: So you want to convert keys in values.. I think that it's possible, you can see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984129/mongodb-aggregation-project-values-as-keys-and-corresponding-array-value-as-va), but as @jairo-malanay pointed up, it seems a map issue, I think that yo need to consider use your application for that mapping